# Getting size of enum using preprocessor

Tags: c++, boost, enums, boost-preprocessor

I am trying to find a way to calculate the length of an enum, other than adding a "COUNT" element at the end of the enum. I have found a way to use the preprocessor as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>

//simple declaration
template <class E>
struct enum_size;

//specialization is done in the macro for each enum created
#define MAKE_ENUM(name, ...) enum name {__VA_ARGS__};   \
  template <>                       \
  struct enum_size<name> {                  \
    static const int value = BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__);   \
    };

MAKE_ENUM(my_enum1, a, b, c)
//MAKE_ENUM(my_enum2, a) //triggers compilation error

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << enum_size<my_enum1>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However when I try to create `my_enum2` as above I get a redeclaration error from the compiler (GCC 4.8.3 on CygWin) as follows

```
main.cpp:16:21: error: redeclaration of 'a'
 MAKE_ENUM(my_enum2, a)
                 ^
main.cpp:9:41: note: in definition of macro 'MAKE_ENUM'
 #define MAKE_ENUM(name, ...) enum name {__VA_ARGS__}; \
                                     ^
main.cpp:15:21: note: previous declaration 'my_enum1 a'
 MAKE_ENUM(my_enum1, a, b, c)
                 ^
main.cpp:9:41: note: in definition of macro 'MAKE_ENUM'
 #define MAKE_ENUM(name, ...) enum name {__VA_ARGS__}; \
```

If I change the problematic line to `MAKE_ENUM(my_enum2, e)` then it compiles cleanly. Any ideas what is wrong here and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend that you run GCC command preprocessor only, not the compiler, and study the generated output after macro expansion, which ought to make your problem clear   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html   http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html#SEC11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `a` has already type `my_enum1`, you cannot redeclare it. You can fix this by few ways

1) If you have C++11 use `enum class`, instead of `enum`.

```
#define MAKE_ENUM(name, ...) enum class name {__VA_ARGS__};
```

2) You can just put `enum` into `namespace`.

Comment: Won't `name ## __VA_ARGS__` add `name` to just the first variable?

Comment: @ForEver: Thanks, I completely missed that point. Solution 1) will work just fine!